# Bar colors in plotly bar chart appear grayed out

Tags: python, colors, plotly, bar-chart

I am trying to plot a group bar chart with the dataframe shown below in image using plotly but I am unable to see colours in the bar. Could someone please help me fix this?

[image]

Attached is the dataframe image
[image]

Below is my python code:

```
fig_bar_ = px.bar(tidy, x='kmeans', y='value',  barmode='group', color = 'variable')
fig_bar_.show()
```

Comment: did the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 2):

You do see the bars, but the colors appear grayed out because each bar is composed of hundreds of stacked rectangles with a tiny space between them.

If you're only interested in the totals for each category (as you seem to be), this should do:

```
tidy = tidy.groupby(['kmeans','variable']).sum().reset_index(level=[0,1])
fig_bar_ = px.bar(tidy, x='kmeans', y='value',  barmode='group', color = 'variable')
fig_bar_.show()
```